# c# WinForm if dynamic checkbox is checked (access from a different function)

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, checked

This is what I have...

```
private void blablabla()
{
  for (int i=1; i<count+1; i++)
  {
    int item_number = panelBoats.Controls.Count;
    CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
    chb.Name = "CheckBoxBoat" + i.ToString();
    chb.Text = "Boat " + i.ToString();
    chb.Location = new Point(10, item_number * 15);
    panelBoats.Controls.Add(chb);
  }
}
```

This is what I wish would work...

```
private void plotMarker(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(CheckBoxBoat0.Checked)
    {
         MessageBox.Show('Yehaaa');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you wanna be able to access the checkbox from a different function in the same class or is it in a different class?

Comment: It's in the same class

Comment: move `CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();` to a form level declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you can do is have a list of checkbox in your class

```
List<CheckBox> myCheckBoxList = new List<CheckBox>();
```

And when you create a checkbox you add it to the list

```
private void blablabla()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
    {
        int item_number = panelBoats.Controls.Count;
        CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
        chb.Name = "CheckBoxBoat" + i.ToString();
        chb.Text = "Boat " + i.ToString();
        chb.Location = new Point(10, item_number * 15);
        panelBoats.Controls.Add(chb);

        //Add the checkBox to the list
        myCheckBoxList.add(chb);
    }
}
```

And then you can access it by using the list

```
private void plotMarker(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (myCheckBoxList[0].Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Schow('Yehaaa');
    }
}
```

Comment: Waow... that was a strange and good idea!  Thx a lot. It work perfectly well and it is simple... Thx again